# connecting wolf`s miner to monero daemon

Tags: cryptonote, daemon, cryptonight

I want to start solo-gpu mining with wolf`s amd miner. in the config file i put daemon+tcp://localhost:18781 and so far its connecting to the daemon but I'm getting following message:

"Setting up GPU(s)"

"Successfully connected to daemon"

"Invalid username / wallet address"

how do I tell the daemon the username and pass to start with to accept the connection from wolfs miner, or maybe I'm wrong with the config file of wolfs miner?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is my config:

`{
    "Algorithms":
    [
        {
            "name": "CryptoNight",
            "devices":
            [
                {
                    "index": 0,
                    "corefreq": 500,
                    "memfreq": 1500,
                    "fanspeed": 65,
                    "powertune": 20,
                    "threads": 1,
                    "rawintensity": 640,
                    "worksize": 16
                },
                {
                    "index": -1,
                    "threads": 2,
                    "rawintensity": 16,
                    "worksize": 16
                }
            ],
            "pools":
            [
                {
                    "url": "daemon+tcp://127.0.0.1:18081",
                    "user": "4262DpuALSSiXgTZnZyuqaeJPbGFkRofkbdE2skF52xMHMnwtYceCw9CikUv44cC7bP1ejqSzE5dN18LagZkins4UBSjZUX",
                    "pass": "x"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: copied your config, still get the error:
`[01:23:02] Setting up GPU(s).
[01:23:07] Successfully connected to daemon.
[01:23:07] Invalid username / wallet address`

Comment: is there maybe any password in the daemon for connecting to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your username should be your wallet address, and you shouldn't need a password.

It would be helpful to see what you are trying to use for your config, but since you didn't post it, I'll just reference an example that I saw somewhere else on stackexchange.

```
{
"Algorithms":
[
    {
        "name": "CryptoNight",
        "devices":
        [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "corefreq": 1000,
                "memfreq": 1300,
                "fanspeed": 65,
                "powertune": 20,
                "threads": 1,
                "rawintensity": 1040,
                "worksize": 16
            }
        ],
        "pools":
        [
            {
                "url": "stratum+tcp://pool_here",
                "user": "43CvTMvvjn5A5ZvfKRRYjPu2m2difVRDA54mqBHGUi5qsjBGWb4zRJvDvn5F6AQJGw9k",
                "pass": "x"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is someone else's config file. I cut out part of their wallet address because privacy. But you should be able to setup your login details similarly to how they did it by having the lines to specify the user and pass details. Your user should be your wallet address and you can most likely leave pass as x like they did.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I can`t figure out how to write "code" in the answer, but anyway I tried it like in your showed in your answer. insead of stratum I have daemon+tcp://localhost:18781and for user and pass I have tried almost everything - wallet, x, username... the same for the password. It would work for pool mining, but what do I write in the config for solo gpu mining?

Comment: @DmitriSenatorov I read what you wrote in your comment on my post and on the other guy's post. I know you have said you have tried anything. But just to clarify, is your wallet address 95 characters long? All monero addresses should be 95 characters. There was someone in the monero slack that was having the same problem and it turned out that they somehow got a phony wallet address. If that doesn't solve it then I am not sure what else it would be. You should probably just be pool mining anyways. Solo mining is not profitable with 1 gpu lol